# После removeView не очищается оперативка

Tags: java, android

программно добавляю элемент

`Screen.addView(ImageView);`

затем делаю

`Screem.revomeView(ImageView)`

почему после этого не очищается оперативка  занимаемая приложением (конкретно элементом `ImageView`)?

Если `ImageView.setBackgroundResource(0);`
Картинка пропадает (что логично), но память занимаемая опять же не очищается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очисткой памяти в Java занимается сборщик мусора. Он вызывается в неопределённое время. И если в момент следующего вызова на `ImageView` не будет активных ссылок, то память очистится. Подробнее, [как работает сборка мусора в Java](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/08/12/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0.html).